# Changing multiple attributes on multiple selectors does not work?

Tags: jquery, attributes, clone, css-selectors

I am trying to learn and understand jquery and I'm having some trouble with multiple selectors. I can't seem to update the attributes, id and name, when I have a cloned jquery object in one of my selectors.

### HTML

```
<div class="File">
    Choose a file:
<input id="File0" name="File0" type="file" />
</div>

<input id="AddFile" type="button" value="Add a File" />

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

### Jquery

```
 var lastId = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#AddFile").click(function () {
            var id = "File" + ++lastId;
            var myInput = $(".File:first").clone(true);

            // Why doesn't this update the input of type 'file' 
            // on the page when selecting multiple selectors?
            $("input:file", myInput ).attr({ id: id, name: id });

             //But if you have omit 'myInput' like this, it will work.
             // $("input:file").attr({ id: id, name: id });

             //This will also work
             //$('#div1, #div2').attr({ id: id, name: id });

             //If I add in the cloned object at the end, it will only
             //modify the input element and not the div with class=File
             //imyInput.insertBefore("#AddFile");
        });
 });
```

When I run the code above. No matter how many times I click on the AddFile button, the dom still reads id="File0" name="File0" type="file"."

Comment: What is ++lastId? It's throwing an error. http://jsfiddle.net/yWVhC/

Comment: `});` is missing in your JS code block at the end.

Comment: I've initialized lastId to correct that error. http://jsfiddle.net/yWVhC/1/

Comment: 1. Added missing });
2. ++lastId increments the variable. Works with ie, and visual studio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not valid in jQuery:

```
$("input:file", myInput ).attr({ id: id, name: id });
```

In the above, myInput will change attributes, but the first input element will not change.

First add the cloned object to the DOM:

```
var myInput = $(".File:first").clone(true).appendTo("body");
```

Then change the attributes:

```
myInput.attr({ id: id, name: id });
```

Comment: I see. And thank you for that. But what I don't understand is why using multiple selectors with a cloned object, that does not yet exist in the dom, does not affect the first object selected. http://jsfiddle.net/W5AQV/

Comment: I don't think "$("input:file", myinput)" is a valid multiple selector in jQuery. Multiple selectors: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/. And some idiot downvotes without an explanation.

Comment: I guess you can't mix a jquery selector with an existing object. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the cloned object. Either add the cloned object or replace with existing one.

**Note: When using the .clone() method, you can modify the cloned elements or their contents before (re-)inserting them into the document.** (http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

And if you want to update only the id and name, you can use this JS fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/22wja/2/**

JS:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastId = 1;
    $("#AddFile").click(function () {
        var id = "File" + ++lastId;
        var myInput = $(".File:first");

        $(myInput).attr({
            id: id,
            name: id
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: If I add the cloned object at the end like this:

myitem.insertBefore("#AddFile")

It doesn't change the name or id attribute of the div with class=File. It only changes the input element. Why is that?

Comment: Try this one :- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/22wja/4/ 


`var myInput = $(".File:first").clone(true).insertBefore("#AddFile");`

Comment: Yes that works. I just don't understand why using multiple selectors with a cloned object, it doesn't update the div.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/22wja/6/, this works with multiple selectors also.

Comment: That changes the input, but I would expect the `<div class="File">` to have an id and name attribute since I pass it myInput. But it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine. I've initialized the var lastId and used appendTo() to put the clones in the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/yWVhC/2/

```
var lastId = 0;

$("#AddFile").click(function () {
    var id = "File" + ++lastId;
    var myInput = $(".File:first").clone(true).appendTo('body');

    // Why doesn't this update the input of type 'file' 
    // on the page when selecting multiple selectors?
    $("input:file", myInput).attr({
        id: id,
        name: id
    });
});
```

You'll need to be more clear about the problem if this doesn't cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/fcscd/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var lastId = 0;
  $("#AddFile").click(function () {
      var id = "File" + (++lastId);
      var myInput = $(".File:first").clone(true).insertAfter(".File:last");

      myInput.attr({
          id: id,
          name: id
      });
  });
});
```

Clone and insert the element after the last `<div class="File">` and then update the attributes